# Como colocar uma moldura ou espaço entre EditText's?

Tags: android, xml

Eu tenho 3 `EditText`'s num layout que estão distribuídos os pesos entre elas, porém quando dou fundo com um cor, da a impressão de que é uma só, teria um método de editar melhor ou colocar uma margem?

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/M00"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#0000ff"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:inputType="numberSigned|numberDecimal"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/M01"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#0000ff"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:inputType="numberSigned|numberDecimal"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/M02"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#0000ff"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:inputType="numberSigned|numberDecimal"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Bom, a margem você pode usar o parâmetro `android:layout_margin`, e quando você diz "moldura", está se referindo a uma borda nestes campos de texto?

Comment: Sim, exatamente isso

Comment: @PauloRodrigues android:layou_margin resolveria, mas deu erro ao colocar no EditText

Comment: Você usou `layou_margin` mesmo, sem o **t**, ou foi só erro de digitação aqui?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sobre a margem, como eu comentei, você pode utilizar o parâmetro `android:layout_margin` em cada um de seus `EditText`s, por exemplo:

```
android:layout_margin="3dp"
```

Isso inclui margem nos quatro cantos, mas se preferir pode incluir somente na esquerda ou direita, onde for necessário, com `layout_marginRight` ou `layout_marginLeft`. Lembrando que para isso será também necessário os parâmetros `layout_marginStart` e `layout_marginEnd`.

Para as bordas, você precisa criar um arquivo dentro do diretório **res/drawable** que representará o *background* do `EditText`. Dei o nome de **edittext_bg.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#0000ff"/>
    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#ffffff"/>
    <corners android:radius="3dp"/>
</shape>
```

Neste exemplo, a caixa de texto vai ficar com o fundo azul (`#0000ff`), borda branca (`#ffffff`) e arredondadas (`3dp`). Esta é uma implementação básica, mas você pode incrementar ainda mais como por exemplo mudar ao ter foco e etc.

E então, só alterar o *background* do `EditText`:

```
android:background="@drawable/edittext_bg"
```